# How to pull all submodules changes

Tags: git, git-submodules

The scenario is:

I have some submodules with some branches.

- sdk (develop, release-1.0)
- api (develop, release-1.0)

And everytime that I need to build my app I just do this

```
git checkout develop && git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout develop
```

but then I have to move over every submodule folder and do the pull in the specific branch that I want to.

I'm asking if there is a way to do the same recursive command with pull on specific branch.

Comment: You could make a script.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: pull-all.sh: cd you-submodule && git checkout develop

Comment: friend but checkout is not my question I need to do pull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while, I found this command.

```
git pull origin branch_name && git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin branch_name
```

which is working fine for me.

Also, I have tested with different ways and I found that

```
git branch && git submodule foreach --recursive git branch
```

helped me to check in every submodule which branch I was checking out.

Hope that helps you guys!

Comment: It's been 9 months and I keep coming back to this answer to update my submodules.
`git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master`
is the command to run when you need to update a third-party open source project you know nothing about. I sometimes need to first run
`git submodule foreach --recursive git reset`